# Using PHP, within a search, how do I contain an html link in an image from my MySql database?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

This is my problem: I have an ecommerce website, and I would like my search results to come up with products that have their links avaiable either within the image of the product on the search page, or next to the image. My current code looks like this:

```
if($_GET['searchBox'] !='')
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($searchresult)==0) {
        echo 'Your search returned no results';
    }
    else 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult))]
        {
           echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'/>".'   '.$row['name'].'   £'.$row['price'].'    '.$row['ProductUrl'];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have spent ages trying to get an URL into the image area, but I can't make it work.

Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is the problem? What doesn't work? What does `$row["image"]` contain? What does the generated HTML code look like? Is this a programming issue, or a layout issue?

Comment: Thank you :). I don't know what code I need to write to generate an HTML link to go with the relevant product that is searched for ['image'] just contains an image, and that works, but I want an HTML link in there somewehere as well. I think it's a programming issue, as I don't know what code I need to write (it's missing its HTML/link code)

Answer (score 1):

What the problem put image in to the anchor tag.

Have you tried like this

```
 echo "<a href='".$row['ProductUrl']."'><img src='".$row['image']."'/></a>";
```

**EDIT**

```
 echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'/>".'   '.$row['name'].'   £'.$row['price'].'
        <a href="'.$row['ProductUrl']."'>".$row['ProductUrl']."</a>";
```

Comment: I've got the image in, but I want the page link relevant to it, so I need the code to generate the relevant link when it generates the relevant image, is it possible? :)

Comment: http://www.a-everett.the-word.com/results.php?searchBox=blue That's my website, it's not real, just for university. You can see how the search is being currently displayed. 'ProductUrl' is just a text link, can I make it HTTP?

Comment: @Amy: Yes, you can make it just put into the anchor tag

Comment: it's definitely getting there, but the link doesn't seem to work right, is including code that's 'included' in my footer.php after. Is it not closed right? (Sorry, have only been doing PHP for a few weeks) http://www.a-everett.the-word.com/results.php?searchBox=blue

Comment: Ahh I used your first code and it's great - sorted! :D Thank you, else {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchresult)) {
   echo "<a href='".$row['ProductUrl']."'><img src='".$row['image']."'/></a>" .$row['name'].'   £'.$row['price'];

Comment: (Sorry I don't know how to make the code go into its own area box when posting)